# $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\pi)/\mathbb{Q})=$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, transcendence-theory

Perhaps a silly question. I'm trying to understand trascendental field extensions, but I can't find a lot of instructive examples.

> Consider the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)/\mathbb{Q}$. What is its group of automorphism, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\pi)/\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Note that any automorphism is determined by its action on pi.

Comment: The point of $\pi$ being transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ is that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is isomorphic as a field to univariate rational functions $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F$ is a field and $K = F(\alpha)$ is a transcendental extension, then every $F$-automorphism of $K$ is of the form
$$\alpha \mapsto \frac{a\alpha + b}{c\alpha + d},$$
where $a,b,c,d \in F$ with $ad - bc \neq 0$.

Comment: Nice. So $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\pi)/\mathbb{Q})=GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Is there a reference for you result? Thank for your answer!

Comment: It can be deduced from the results of Section 13.2 #18 in Dummit & Foote.

Comment: Thanks, I have a copy. I'll check it out.

Comment: @SamuelPlath: It's not quite $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, because if $b=c=0$ and $a=d$ then the automorphism you get is just the identity.  So you actually get the quotient of $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ by the subgroup of matrices that are scalar multiples of the identity (this quotient is called $PGL_2(\mathbb{Q})$).

Comment: Ah, nice. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @EricWofsey My bad. Thanks for the correction Eric!